# Clean Architecture: ViewModel with multiple UseCases on Android

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture, kotlin, viewmodel

This is more of an Architecture question than a bug fixing one.

Let's assume this app lets users mark a Bus and/or Bus Stations as a favourite. My question is, should I have a `ViewModel` with both UseCases or should I build a UseCase that encapsulates the current logic?

Also for the question part, I'm not entirely sure the way I should expose the combined data to the UI layer (see `favouritesExposedLiveData`)

Thanks in advance any feedback is welcome, here's my `ViewModel` you can assume each UseCase is passing the correct data from the data source(s).

```java
open class FavouritesViewModel @Inject internal constructor(
            private val getFavouriteStationsUseCase: GetFavouriteStationsUseCase,
            private val getFavouriteBusesUseCase: GetFavouriteBusesUseCase,
            private val favouriteMapper: FavouriteMapper,
            private val busMapper: BusMapper,
            private val stationMapper: StationMapper) : ViewModel() {

        private val favouriteBusesLiveData: MutableLiveData<Resource<List<BusView>>> = MutableLiveData()
        private val favouriteStationsLiveData: MutableLiveData<Resource<List<StationView>>> = MutableLiveData()

        private lateinit var favouritesMediatorLiveData: MediatorLiveData<List<FavouriteView>>
        private lateinit var favouritesExposedLiveData: LiveData<Resource<List<FavouriteView>>>

        init {
            fetchFavourites()
        }

        override fun onCleared() {
            getFavouriteStationsUseCase.dispose()
            getFavouriteBusesUseCase.dispose()
            super.onCleared()
        }

        fun getFavourites(): LiveData<Resource<List<FavouriteView>>> {
            return favouritesExposedLiveData
        }

        private fun fetchFavourites() {
            favouritesMediatorLiveData.addSource(favouriteStationsLiveData, { favouriteStationListResource ->
                if (favouriteStationListResource?.status == ResourceState.SUCCESS) {
                    favouriteStationListResource.data?.map {
                        favouriteMapper.mapFromView(it)
                    }
                }
            })

            favouritesMediatorLiveData.addSource(favouriteBusesLiveData, { favouriteBusesListResource ->
                if (favouriteBusesListResource?.status == ResourceState.SUCCESS) {
                    favouriteBusesListResource.data?.map {
                        favouriteMapper.mapFromView(it)
                    }
                }
            })

            getFavouriteStationsUseCase.execute(FavouriteStationsSubscriber())
            getFavouriteBusesUseCase.execute(FavouriteBusesSubscriber())
        }

        inner class FavouriteStationsSubscriber : DisposableSubscriber<List<Station>>() {
            override fun onComplete() {}

            override fun onNext(t: List<Station>) {
                favouriteStationsLiveData.postValue(Resource(ResourceState.SUCCESS, t.map { stationMapper.mapToView(it) }, null))
            }

            override fun onError(exception: Throwable) {
                favouriteStationsLiveData.postValue(Resource(ResourceState.ERROR, null, exception.message))
            }

        }

        inner class FavouriteBusesSubscriber : DisposableSubscriber<List<Bus>>() {
            override fun onComplete() {}

            override fun onNext(t: List<Bus>) {
                favouriteBusesLiveData.postValue(Resource(ResourceState.SUCCESS, t.map { busMapper.mapToView(it) }, null))
            }

            override fun onError(exception: Throwable) {
                favouriteBusesLiveData.postValue(Resource(ResourceState.ERROR, null, exception.message))
            }

        }
    }
```

*Note:* Currently the `MediatorLiveData` (`favouritesMediatorLiveData`)is not binding the data back to the `favouritesExposedLiveData` since at this time, I'm not sure this is the correct way to go ;).

Comment: have you find any solution for the same

Answer (score 1):

Ideally a ViewModel would only have the view state for its view. By using the MediatorLiveData you could aggregate all sources of state into one that represents the view state over time.

What you can have is a data class that represents your ViewState that you construct on your view model and is your exposed LiveData

`data class FavouritesViewState(val favoriteStations: List<Station>, val favoritBuses: List<Bus>)`

However you know depend on the ViewModel to construct the final ViewState which kinda breaks the single responsibility principle and also makes you dependent of an Android framework.

I would approach it using a composite UseCase that had both station and bus use cases and returns the composed data that you can then easily expose from the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a ViewModel is that it is a model of what the view is using.  It should be as close to that as possible.. Unless you are presenting stations and buses in the same view list (seems ugly), otherwise, they are separate views, and should get separate models.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but, you're not really answering the question, and yes I want to display both Buses and Stations (marked as favorites).